# Have index value as nodes while converting XML to Json using Json.Net

Tags: json, xml, list, serialization, json.net

```
I have an input XML as below:

<Options>
<Series>
    <Series>
    <Type>Bar</Type>
    <TargetAxisIndex>1</TargetAxisIndex>
    </Series>
    <Series>
    <Type>Line</Type>
    <TargetAxisIndex>2</TargetAxisIndex>
    </Series>
</Series>

<Title>Test title</Title>

</Options>
```

I am using JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode() and want to have my output as below:

```
{"Series":
  {
   "0": {"Type":"Bar","TargetAxisIndex":"1"},
   "1": {"Type":"Line","TargetAxisIndex":"2"}
  }
"Title":"Test title"
}
```

Is there a way of achieving this? Basically i want the node to be serialized as index.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind going through an intermediate projection through an anonymous class, and switching from `XmlDocument` to the more Linq-friendly `XDocument`, you'll be able to leverage the [Select overload which provides the index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx), and then apply `.ToDictionary` to get the Json shape you need:

```cs
var root = XDocument.Load(pathToMyDocument)
    .Root;

var myObject = new
{
    Title = root.Element("Title").Value,
    Series = root.Element("Series")
        .Elements("Series")
        .Select((node, idx) => 
        new
        {
            Node = node,
            Index = idx
        })
        .ToDictionary(
           e => e.Index,
           e => new 
           {
              Type = e.Node.Element("Type").Value,
              TargetAxisIndex = e.Node.Element("TargetAxisIndex").Value
           })
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
```

**Result:**

```
{
    "Title": "Test title",
    "Series": {
        "0": {
            "Type": "Bar",
            "TargetAxisIndex": "1"
        },
        "1": {
            "Type": "Line",
            "TargetAxisIndex": "2"
        }
    }
}
```

Another alternative may be to do the dictionary and indexing manipulation in XSLT, before using `SerializeXmlNode`, by using the [`position()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/929126/314291), although you'll need to subtract 1 - it's one based.